# Android Studio fail to install apk automatically, because AS use a incorrect name

Tags: android-studio, installation-path

I have declared versionName 1.1.8 in gradle file
AS generates apk file under the outputs folder, say MyApp-1.1.8-release
But when AS install the apk, it uses a path named with MyApp-1.1.0-release
I can not search the words "1.1.0" in the whole project
I don't know where AS find the wrong version name

Can we config app name in AS?

Comment: Hello Xiao Jiang and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Have you tried anything yet? Showing what you have already tried helps a lot. Your question may also be a duplicate: have you searched Stackoverflow for similar responses?

Comment: Before I edited my question, I have searched this issue, but no useful answers. I know the direct cause of this issue is that AS uses wrong apk path, but I don't know why AS does it

Comment: You should write the specific steps you've undertaken: it will help people who land on this page too in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project, sync Gradle, then re-run the app.
But it didn't work last Saturday. Actually, the root cause didn't be found